# What is the name given to these geometric designs?

Tags: style-identification

The design given in the picture is very impressive and many such designs have been used as background images and also as components in certain flat illustrations.

Is there a name for this style?

[image: This is the image referred to in the question]

Comment: Hi Afthab Ali, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 6):

Do a Google search for "low poly background".

There are a lot of generators for this kind of images:

- http://dmesh.thedofl.com/
- http://qrohlf.com/trianglify

Comment: +1 for trianglify. There's also: http://matthew.wagerfield.com/flat-surface-shader/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial that I followed to make a low-poly design

The main points I liked this tutorial is that it was really easy to follow and it didn't jump from part to part, thats especially helpful for a beginner

By the way I enjoyed the speedart video

http://www.digitalartsonline.co.uk/tutorials/adobe-illustrator/create-low-poly-portrait/

Comment: Could you please include the main points of the tutorial in your answer? That way, your answer is still valuable if the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really, really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks!

Comment: Agh.. sorry fixed it now

Comment: Uh... what I meant is the gist of the *method* used in the tutorial. As-is, your answer is still not of very much use in case the link goes dead, I'm sorry. Thanks for trying, tho! :)